# Is there a bandwidth limit on firebase functions?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a function that request releases from a private GitHub repository to save it in the firebase's cloud storage. It works perfectly in the emulators (local testing), but I don't know if there will be a problem when deploying the production version.

It should be clarified that there is no data transfer between the function and the user, but the server only requests the file from GitHub to save it directly in the cloud-storage.

Here is a small example of what my function does:

```js
// MY APP ;
async function checkForUpdates( ) {
  const fn = httpsCallable( functions, 'githubUpdateStoredRepository' ) ;
  const res : HttpsCallableResult = await fn( 'my-repo' ) ;
  if( res.data.updated == true ) {
    console.log( 'release file updated' ) ;
  }
}

// FIREBASE FUNCTIONS
export const updateRelease = onCall( async ( data, context : CallableContext ) => {
  const repoName = data ;
  // get release file from github.
  const file = await getFile( repoName ) ; // <= "octokit/rest"
  // save the release file in the firebase storage.
  const blob = bucket.file( 'my-release-file.zip' ) ;
  await blob.save( file ) ; // <= Buffer (~40MB).
  // only lets the user know that the file is updated.
  return { updated : true } ;
} ) ;
```

The release files are around ~40MB. I searched in documentation, but I can't find anything concerning my specific situation.

Thank you for your help.

I've tested the function in a local environment (firebase-emulators) and it works perfectly, but I don't know if it will work once the production version is released or if it will have a significant impact on the project's invoicing.

Comment: Your code has no error handling or exception catching.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what you mean by "bandwidth limit", or what might not work when you deploy this code.  But you certainly can transfer as much data as you want inside your function, for as long as your function is allowed to run, as long as you're willing to pay the ingress and egress fees associated with all products in used.  You might want to read:

- [Cloud Functions pricing documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing)
- [Cloud Storage billing documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing)